# Are there post-quantum cryptosystems with a gap between classical and quantum security?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, complexity, hardness-assumptions, quantum-cryptanalysis

Is there a gap between classical attacks and quantum attacks against some post-quantum security assumptions? (I'm particularly interested in asymmetric cryptography.)

I understand that there is no polynomial-time algorithm against these problems (otherwise it will no longer be considered as a PQ security assumption). But is it sometimes the case that we know more efficient quantum attacks than classical attacks (even if it's still exponential)?

Comment: You can run standard algorithms on a quantum computer. So even if there is a gap, it would not be a gap for somebody owning a big quantum computer, I suppose.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes But those standard algorithms might require more memory than the quantum computer has. In that way, it's just as capable of running all standard algorithms as a classical computer is of running quantum algorithms (it can, but the amount of memory it would require would be inconceivable).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example where the best known quantum attack is, in a sense, just "halfway" between the best known classical attack on one side, and a complete break on the other:
Inverting a **cryptographic group action** such as [CSIDH](//ia.cr/2018/383).

Let $G$ be a (finite) commutative group $G$ acting on a set $X$, i.e., we consider a map
$$ \ast\colon\; G\times X\to X$$
that is compatible with the group structure of $G$ in the sense that $1\ast x=x$ and $(g\cdot h)\ast x=g\ast(h\ast x)$.

The problem to be solved is analogous to the discrete-logarithm problem:

> Given two elements $x,y\in X$, find $g\in G$ with $g\ast x=y$, assuming it exists.

---

**Classically**, the best known attack is a meet-in-the-middle approach à la baby-step giant-step, where the group $G$ is split into two subsets $U,V\subseteq G$ such that $G=U\cdot V$, and one looks for a collision between the two sets $U\ast x$ and $V^{-1}\ast y$. Indeed, when $u\ast x=v^{-1}\ast y$, then $(u\cdot v)\ast x=y$. This takes time and space $O(\!\sqrt{\lvert G\rvert})$, which is **exponential** in $\log{\lvert G\rvert}$.

<sub>(In reality, there are better time-space tradeoffs than this simplistic approach.)</sub>

**Quantumly** however, this problem can be attacked using Kuperberg's algorithm [[1](//arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0302112),[2](//arxiv.org/abs/1112.3333)] for the *abelian hidden shift* problem, and this takes **subexponential** (but superpolynomial) time in the group size. More concretely, the asymptotic cost is
$$ {\exp}\Big(\!\sqrt{\log{\lvert G\rvert}}+o(1)\Big) \text, $$
which can be roughly summarized as "taking a square root in the exponent".

<sub>(For comparison, the number field sieve for integer factorization is also subexponential, but with a *cube* root.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and do you know if there is a similar phenomena with some lattice problem?